# Vue 3 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: parent is null - Composition API

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-composition-api

I have a component with setup and using composition API. On mounted, I make a call to server and while the call is waiting for the request I show a loading icon. For some weird reason, I get this error message

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: parent is null
```

My Code is setup like this:

```
<script setup>
import {useRoute} from "vue-router";
import {onMounted, reactive, ref} from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
const subject = ref("");
const isLoading = ref(true);

onMounted( async function () {
    await axios.get('/mycallurl/something' + route.params.uuid}).then((res) => {
        subject.value = res.data.subject; //a string
       isLoading.value = false;
    });
});
```

I have tried to set the `isLoading` value in a second "then" like this,

```
onMounted( async function () {
    await axios.get('/mycallurl/something' + route.params.uuid}).then((res) => {
        subject.value = res.data.subject; //a string
    }).then(()=>{isLoading.value = false; });
});
```

I also tried initializing **isLoading** as null  like isLoading = ref(null);

all of which bring the error.

It only works when I put `isLoading.value = false;` after the onMounted() block like:

```
onMounted( async function () {
    await axios.get('/mycallurl/something' + route.params.uuid}).then((res) => {
       subject.value = res.data.subject; //a string
}).then(()=>{isLoading.value = false; });
});

setTimeout(function(){

  isLoading.value = false;

}, 2000); //assuming after 2 secs the request has succeeded
```

I have banged my head and tried a few things and after 1 hr I would appreciate any insights on this!

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. Script alone can't cause this error. This is specific to what happens in a template and how the comps are related

Comment: Found this [related github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/5657).  Seems more related to template code than script code.

Comment: @EstusFlask What I provided is exactly that. The only options I remain with is to use the Options Api and I will let you guys know how that goes. In the <template></template> I only have a div with an icon tag like 

`<template><div><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" v-if="isLoading"></i></div></template>`

Comment: Please, check the link above and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . SO rules require to provide reproducible code in order for a problem to be solved. Currently it's not reproducible, this is regular vue code that's expected to work. If you're not sure if it is reproducible, you can confirm this yourself on https://play.vuejs.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was simply moving the v-if condition to a parent div and not the actual icon.

From

```
<template>
  <div>
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" v-if="isLoading"></i>
  </div>
</template>
```

To

```
<template>
  <div  v-if="isLoading">
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
  </div>
</template>
```

if I have the time I will dig deeper, but this is what ended up working

Comment: Can't you do change to *v-show*? And the code may look like: ```<div> <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" v-show="isLoading"></i> </div>```

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation Thanks for the contribution. **When I use v-show on the i element**, it does not generate the error message, but it does not show either. If I put v-show on the parent div, it shows exactly as described in the answer I provided

    `<div v-show="formData.loading">
          <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
    </div>`  Works